# Protractor: Not able to retrieve all the values from multiple rows in a web-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have a web-table with multiple rows. I want retrieve that data and verify. But for some reason my method only return the value from first row. Can some one tell what is wrong?

Method:

```
    validatePolicyVersionTable(){
       return element.all(by.repeater('row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)')).then(numOfRows=>{
           let length = numOfRows.length;
           let tableDataArray = [];
           for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               let rows= element(by.repeater('row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)').row(i));
               let cells = rows.all(by.tagName('td'));
               tableDataArray= cells.map(cellText=>{
                  return cellText.getText();
               });
           }
           return tableDataArray;
       })
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this

```js
validatePolicyVersionTable() {
  const rows = element.all(by.repeater('row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)'));

  return rows.map((row) => row.$$('td').getText());
}
```

If you are fetching the text of an `ElementArrayFinder` you would get back an array of strings (the `row.$$('td').getText()`). Your result could be something like this

```
[
  ['row1CellText1', 'row1CellText2', 'row1CellText3'],
  ['row2CellText1', 'row2CellText2', 'row2CellText3'],
  ['row3CellText1', 'row3CellText2', 'row3CellText3']
]
```